# Build something like JavaDoc for HTML-Templates...

Tags: java, templates, architecture

To improve my skills a had witten a small template engine in Java.
In principle, it operates as the others...

```
<div>
    <tpl:include file="global/A.html"/>
</div>
<!-- .... -->
<div>
    <tpl:include file="global/B.html"/>
</div>
```

Now i want to build a software which shows me the dependencies between the templates. Something like JavaDoc... which template includes which template etc. That works fine.

For the root template i want to build a hierarchically tree which shows me the entire path. How can i do that? Do i have to open the first included file, study and save the information's about that and do the whole recursively? Just like open the root template > Open the first include > study this sub template > go to the sub sub template [...] go back to the first included template and do the hole thing again with a second include?

For a little push I would be grateful!
By the

Answer (score 0):

Close, you want a check to keep you from reprocessing...
Create a list, and a hashmap

1. Start with your full template list, put them into the list.
2. Iterate the list, for each record:
3. Check the hashmap for the record, if it exists, return that, otherwise, create new hashmap entry for template object, and recursively add child templates as children to the template object.

This keeps you from continuously reprocessing those templates that you have already seen.